# Sqoop command not working with Symantec Anti Virus

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, symantec

I am trying to run Sqoop command to get data from RDBMS it is working fine in
local environment where there is no anti virus installed but the same code is throwing error in Prod as there we are having Symantec Antivirus installed.
I don't know how to resolve this. Below is my Sqoop command.

```
sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://x.xx.xx.xx\\S167;database=DMF;username=test;password=test";
```

i am getting below error.

> ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user

Please help.

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with Symantec? it looks more like the database username and password are wrong. I'm assuming your prod username and password aren't both `test`?

Comment: As @Ben Watson suggested check with the username and password for prod, and also do a telnet test to check if you are reachable to the sql server from prod : Example telnet <Your hostname/IP> <port>

Comment: @BenWatson yes i have posted dummy username and password here but with the actual username and password i am able to login in my sql server client but when i use it in sqoop then only i am getting error. I tried the same thing in machines where antivirus is not present and in machines where antivirus is present, it is not working with machines antivirus is installed.

Comment: @roh yes here i have posted dummy username and password but i am using correct username and password as i am able to login in the sql server client using same credentials.

Comment: Even if it doesn't make sense when it worked in your lab env, but can you try passing username and password separately, something like this : sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://x.xx.xx.xx\\S167' --username <username> --password <password>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of trial and error i finally found the solution. I removed double quotes **(" ")** and added single quote **(' ')** and i removed one forward slash ()then it worked for me.
Below is the modified code:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://x.xx.xx.xx\S167;database=DMF;username=test;password=test';
```

i feel because the address in an instance we have to use single quote otherwise double quotes. Can someone please help with actual reason.